# Is getIfPresent considered as a get operation for expireAfterAccess?

Tags: java, guava

Does the `getIfPresent` function reset the time for `expireAfterAccess`?

Comment: Yep. But an `asMap().containsKey(key)` shouldn't. But note that most usages should be `expireAfterWrite` if you want to expire based on staleness (e.g. access might be a session data).

Comment: @BenManes, you saved my day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`CacheBuilder.expireAfterAccess()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterAccess-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) docs say:

> Access time is reset by all cache read and write operations

Since `Cache.getIfPresent()` is a cache read, it resets the access time.